# Extract only values from json that matches with good columns list

Tags: python, json

I am reading a csv file in python and extracting the column containing json data and extracting the required key-value pairs. So I have given the list of good columns(say `good_columns =[]`) that I want on my list and I am appending the values for that key in new list(say `data=[]`) but in json some keys are there that I don't want according to my good column list for that I want to add zero to my data list.
Thanks in advance.

```
good_columns = [
    "outboundrtp_roundTripTime",
    "outboundrtp_targetBitrate",
    "outboundrtp_bytesSent",
    "outboundrtp_packetsSent",
    "outboundrtp_packetsLost",
    "inboundrtp_inboundJitter" ,
    "inboundrtp_bytesReceived" ,
    "inboundrtp_packetsLost"
    ]
```

json content:

```
{
"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency": 0,
"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency": 165,
"outboundrtp_roundTripTime": 0.340,
"outboundrtp_targetBitrate": 17586,
"outboundrtp_bytesSent": 8880,
"outboundrtp_packetsSent": 78,
"outboundrtp_packetsLost": 1,
"outboundrtp_remb": 0,
"inboundrtp_inboundJitter": 0.024,
"inboundrtp_bytesReceived": 24835,
"inboundrtp_packetsLost": 0,
"inboundrtp_remb": 0
}

{
"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency": 0,
"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency": 149,
"outboundrtp_roundTripTime": 0,
"outboundrtp_targetBitrate": 5616,
"outboundrtp_bytesSent": 37366,
"outboundrtp_packetsSent": 654,
"outboundrtp_packetsLost": 0,
"outboundrtp_remb": 0
}
```

I want my list to contain with value 0 for the keys, not in good columns. So it should give result like:
**for the first one:**
Desired output:

```
[0.340,17586,8880,78,1,0.024,24835,0]
```

Current output:

```
[0,0,0.340,17586,8880,78,1,0]
```

**for the second one:**
Desired output:

```
[0,5616,37366,654,0,0,0]
```

Current output:

```
[0,0,0,5616,37366,654,0]
```

**What I have tried:**

```
for key, value in record.items():
    if key in good_columns:
        data.append(value)
    elif key not in good_columns:
        data.append(0)
```

But this is not giving the desired output.

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired output and the current output? On the face of it, this just works for me (assuming `json_content = records` and `data = []`

Comment: Which variable has your json contents? It's quite unclear

Comment: @GaneshK record variable has the json content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# record = json.loads()

for key in good_columns:
    if(key not in record.keys()):
        record[key] = 0
```

Comment: Is record the parsed `json`, if not change the `record` variable to that.

Comment: 'data= [] 
record = df_filter['local'].apply(json.loads) 
for key, value in record.items():
 if key in good_columns:
  data.append(value) 
 elif key not in good_columns:
  data.append(0)'

Comment: In the answer above the `record` dict will contain the required stuff. Then just take the values. Splitting of the key-value pair is inadvisable as the order will change. do `print(record.values())` to get the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
good_columns = [
    "outboundrtp_roundTripTime",
    "outboundrtp_targetBitrate",
    "outboundrtp_bytesSent",
    "outboundrtp_packetsSent",
    "outboundrtp_packetsLost",
    "inboundrtp_inboundJitter" ,
    "inboundrtp_bytesReceived" ,
    "inboundrtp_packetsLost"
    ]
json_data = [{
"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency": 0,
"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency": 165,
"outboundrtp_roundTripTime": 0.340,
"outboundrtp_targetBitrate": 17586,
"outboundrtp_bytesSent": 8880,
"outboundrtp_packetsSent": 78,
"outboundrtp_packetsLost": 1,
"outboundrtp_remb": 0,
"inboundrtp_inboundJitter": 0.024,
"inboundrtp_bytesReceived": 24835,
"inboundrtp_packetsLost": 0,
"inboundrtp_remb": 0
},{
"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency": 0,
"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency": 149,
"outboundrtp_roundTripTime": 0,
"outboundrtp_targetBitrate": 5616,
"outboundrtp_bytesSent": 37366,
"outboundrtp_packetsSent": 654,
"outboundrtp_packetsLost": 0,
"outboundrtp_remb": 0
}]

def get_val(json_dict, val):
    return json_dict.get(val,0)

for index, json_dict in enumerate(json_data,1):
    merge_keys = good_columns + list(json_dict.keys())
    order_keys = list(dict.fromkeys(merge_keys))
    data = [get_val(json_dict,val) for val in order_keys]
    print('{}.Dictionary data is {}'.format(index,data))

>>>1.Dictionary data is [0.34, 17586, 8880, 78, 1, 0.024, 24835, 0, 0, 165, 0, 0]
   2.Dictionary data is [0, 5616, 37366, 654, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 149, 0]
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and in the 2.Dictionary data is [0, 5616, 37366, 654, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 149, 0]  why there are values 149 and 0.

Comment: @AnshulSharma I am merging the good_columns and dictionary keys together then getting values from it.